# Cant see animated GIFs properly in web browser

Tags: windows-7, browser, website, animated-gif

I just recently purchased a netbook with Windows 7 starter edition.  Some websites I go to with this will show animated .gif files properly, but others will not.  One example of a page that doesn't work correctly is http://www.preferencepools.com/about.htm where the second image should rotate through 4 pictures.  This fails in both IE and Firefox, so I know it's not the browser.  Anyone have any ideas why this might be failing?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be symptomatic of an underpowered netbook.

Does the web page finish loading? Try placing the URL of the image directly into your browser's location bar to see what happens.

BTW, your link to about.htm points to the wrong target.

Comment: The page does finish loading.  seems kinda odd that a brand new netbook wouldn't be able to handle the site since it was created using a p3 700 with 64 megs ram originally and this is an atom 1.6 with a full gig of ram...

Comment: Try temporarily disabling your firewall. Apparently ZoneAlarm has an option for disabling animations in its privacy options, and there could be others. This might explain why both IE and FF are affected.  I've tested on an Asus 1005PE with a configuration more or less identical to the one described and can't reproduce the fault.